# Editable table in recycleview then write table to text file

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make an editable table that allows the user to edit its contents. Then I want to be able to write the contents of the table to a file cell by cell. My big problem is that I have not found a way to track/save the changes of my table and also I do not know how to access specific cells of my table. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could create a table that can take the input of the user and then write all the contents of this table to a file.

As of now, I can display my tables using recycleview and they are editable but I don't know how to access the values of each cell from my code. Here is a minimal reproducible example of what I have so far.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
from functools import partial
import csv, datetime, decimal, math, re, os, time
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior

xdata = [{'col1': 'Band Number', 'col2': 'BBF (Hz)', 'col3': 'BEF (Hz)', 'col4': 'SWD (s)', 'col5': 'SWP (0|#)', 'col6': 'RBW (Hz)', 'col7': 'Att (dB)', 'col8': 'Ref (dBm)'
          , 'col9': 'TRM', 'col10': 'Band Info'},
        {'col1': '1', 'col2': '150e6', 'col3': '174e6', 'col4': '0', 'col5': '0', 'col6': '3e3', 'col7': '0', 'col8': '-50', 'col9': 'average'
         , 'col10': 'PS 150MHz'}, # 1
         {'col1': '2', 'col2': '450e6', 'col3': '512e6', 'col4': '0', 'col5': '0', 'col6': '3e3', 'col7': '0', 'col8': '-50', 'col9': 'average'
          , 'col10': 'PS 450MHz'}, # 2
         {'col1': '3', 'col2': '758e6', 'col3': '775e6', 'col4': '0', 'col5': '0', 'col6': '3e3', 'col7': '0', 'col8': '-50', 'col9': 'average'
          , 'col10': 'PS 760MHz'}, # 3
         {'col1': '4', 'col2': '851e6', 'col3': '862e6', 'col4': '0', 'col5': '0', 'col6': '3e3', 'col7': '0', 'col8': '-50', 'col9': 'average'
          , 'col10': 'PS 850MHz'}, # 4
         ]

class Tabelle(BoxLayout):
    pass

class RVScreen(Screen):
    pass

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'spalte1_SP': str(x['col1']), 'spalte2_SP': str(x['col2']), 'spalte3_SP': str(x['col3']),
                      'spalte4_SP': str(x['col4']),'spalte5_SP': str(x['col5']), 'spalte6_SP': str(x['col6']),
                      'spalte7_SP': str(x['col7']), 'spalte8_SP': str(x['col8']), 'spalte9_SP': str(x['col9'])
                      , 'spalte10_SP': str(x['col10'])} for x in xdata]

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = ScreenManager()
        root.add_widget(RVScreen(name='RVScreen'))
        return root



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExampleApp().run()
```

Kv file

```
<Tabelle>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    spalte1_SP: 'spalte1'
    spalte2_SP: 'spalte2'
    spalte3_SP: 'spalte3'
    spalte4_SP: 'col4'
    spalte5_SP: 'col5'
    spalte6_SP: 'col6'
    spalte7_SP: 'col7'
    spalte8_SP: 'col8'
    spalte9_SP: 'col9'
    spalte10_SP: 'col10'

    TextInput:
        id: SP1
        text: root.spalte1_SP
    TextInput:
        id: SP2
        text: root.spalte2_SP
    TextInput:
        id: SP3
        text: root.spalte3_SP
    TextInput:
        id: SP4
        text: root.spalte4_SP
    TextInput:
        id: SP5
        text: root.spalte5_SP
    TextInput:
        id: SP6
        text: root.spalte6_SP
    TextInput:
        id: SP7
        text: root.spalte7_SP
    TextInput:
        id: SP8
        text: root.spalte8_SP
    TextInput:
        id: SP9
        text: root.spalte9_SP
    TextInput:
        id: SP10
        text: root.spalte10_SP
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'Tabelle'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(20)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
<RVScreen>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        RV:
        Button:
            text: 'Save Roll Call Data with RCBC Table'
            size_hint: .40, .25
            pos_hint: {'left': 1}
            on_release: root.save()
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], not pages and pages of code dump.

Comment: My apologies, I have provided new code that shows how I have created my tables.